# How do I load both Strings and floats into a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, io

I need to somehow make numpy load in both text and numbers.

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip00ktest.py", line 13, in <module>
    File = np.loadtxt(str(z[1]))        #load spectrum file 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 805, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): EFF
```

because my file I'm loading in has text in it. I need each word to be stored in an array index as well as the data below it. How do I do that?

Edit: Sorry for not giving an example. Here is what my file looks like.

```
FF   3500.  GRAVITY 0.00000  SDSC GRID  [+0.0]   VTURB 2.0 KM/S    L/H 1.25                            
  wl(nm)    Inu(ergs/cm**2/s/hz/ster) for 17 mu in 1221 frequency intervals
            1.000   .900  .800  .700  .600  .500  .400  .300  .250  .200  .150  .125  .100  .075  .050  .025  .010
    9.09 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    9.35 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    9.61 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    9.77 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    9.96 0.000E+00     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

There are thousands of numbers below the ones shown here. Also, there are different datasets within the file such that the header you see on top repeats, followed by a new set of new numbers.

Code that Fails:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from math import *

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)

z = np.array(sys.argv)          #store all of the file names into array

i = len(sys.argv)           #the length of the filenames array

File = np.loadtxt(str(z[1]))        #load spectrum file
```

Comment: you need to give more details about the structure of your file.

Comment: how big is the file? Can you load the whole thing in memory?

Comment: I think so. I just tried to use lists, and readlines() doesn't give an error. I assume that means it is not too big?

Comment: You could split the file into separate chunk by looking at the lines where the header starts, then load those into numpy to create separate arrays. Or something like that. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the line that messes it up always begins with `EFF`, then you can ignore that line quite easily:

```
np.loadtxt(str(z[1]), comments='EFF')
```

Which will treat any line beginning with `'EFF'` as a comment and it will be ignored.

Comment: I really wish I would've seen this earlier. I ended up having to make a counter in the file (since the data sets within were uniform), and having certain arrays reset to 0 after it reached a new "EFF" line. You have just save me a lot of time in the future though. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To read the numbers, use the `skiprows` parameter of `numpy.loadtxt` to skip the header. Write custom code to read the header, because it seems to have an irregular format.

NumPy is most useful with homogenous numerical data -- don't try to put the strings in there.

Comment: This would be useful, except that the header repeats itself. It'll just screw up once it reaches the header again for a new set of data within the file.

Comment: @user2378781 Then read the file line by line, examine the string and decide what to do with each line.